# TextView overrides other views with ConstraintView

Tags: android, textview, android-constraintlayout, android-wrap-content

I have been trying to create a simple textView (we'll call it "Body") with some little text below - we'll call it ("More").

My plan is to have the "Body" TextView taking as much as it requires, and just below - is the "More" text view.

I constrained "Body" to the top, and "More" to just below it. With or without constraints to "parent" as bottom.

Unfortunately, when "Body" grows too high - it kicks "More" out of the screen.

[image: Bottom TextView gets kicked off screen]

The only way it doesn't - is when I define a chain. But then - the views settle in the middle of the screen, when I want them to settle on top.

Any way out of it?

Thanks

Comment: Define the chain and add `app:layout_constraintVertical_Bias=0` to first view to align it to the top instead of center.

Comment: That's great when the body text is full. But when it's small...it offensively ignores my vertical bias! :-(